# Need a list of Groups from Active Directory for a given user when offline

Tags: delphi, authentication, winapi, active-directory, ldap

I'm working in an application that authenticates a username/password against Active Directory via LDAP, and retrieves a list of all the Groups the user belongs to. These Groups determine their privilege level within the application. This works fine when Active Directory is available.

In the case where the network is down and/or Active Directory isn't available, I need to both:

1. Authenticate the username/password
2. Retrieve a list of the AD Groups associated with the user

I can accomplish #1 by using the LogonUser Windows API call. What I can't figure out is how to get the list of AD Groups for the user. I'm not even sure if that information is stored when a user logs into the computer and their credentials are cached. So my questions are:

1. Are the user's AD Groups stored in the windows local credential cache?
2. If they are stored, how do I extract them programmatically from the Windows credential cache?

Comment: When a user logs on to the domain, they're assigned a security token that includes the information about their group membership. It is discarded when they logoff.  So the answer to #1 is No.

Comment: You can't authenticate the username/password if the network is not available. If the user is logging into the same machine they were on last, they may be able to use cached credentials to log into the machine itself, but that's about it. You can't retrieve a list of the AD group memberships for that user, though; fthere is nothing to retrieve that list from if the network isn't there, and they're not cached because they could change at any time and a membership revoked, so they're read at login and discarded completely at logoff.